# Moving JS scripts to an external file in Node.js' express served Html page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use express that returns me some html page:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/views/index.html'));
});
```

That `index.html` contains a bunch of scripts in the tag `<script></script>`.

I would like to move it to an external file like this:

```
<script src="./indexScripts.js"></script>
```

However it doesn't work and returns the following errors:

> GET http://.../indexScripts.js net::ERR_ABORTED
>
> GET http://.../indexScripts.js 404 (Not Found)

Would you have any clue on what I should do?

A solution I found is exposing the script:

```
app.get('/scripts', function(req, res){
    return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/views/indexScripts.js'));
});
```

... then using it:

```
<script src="scripts"></script>
```

But it really seems not the correct way of handling this / prone to security breach...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Express won't serve static files (JavaScript, CSS and images). You need to use the `express.static` middleware to explicitly tell Express which folders it should serve from the file system.

Example:

`app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')))`

Then you can get your script file by navigating to `http://localhost:3000/indexScripts.js`.

You can read more about the `static` middleware [here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: Thank you! I was concerned about the security aspects but seems the dotfiles option is the one to go for :-)